# Vce voltage bias

Tags: amplifier, design

I am building a multistage audio amplifier with a 10V supply. I am wondering about the affect this point (collector voltage, 5.6668167V) has on the performance of the circuit. If, at the output, I find no clipping, does it really matter that this isnt half the voltage source? What problems would it cause, if any? [image]

Comment: Since you have some voltage drop across the emitter resistor the collector voltage for maximum swing wouldn't be at 1/2VCC anyway. The load you place on the amplifier will also affect the optimum voltage level.

Comment: Note that your biasing resistors are probably too high in value. The biasing point is too dependent upon the bjt beta.

Comment: You do realize that most of the digits in your displayed voltages are meaningless. Considering the tolerances of your power supply and the resistors,  probably in the range of 2-5%, the value for the collector voltage should be taken as 5.7 volts. Unless you  have a very tight requirement on output voltage, this is probably good enough.

Comment: Curiosity, You'll need to respond to thoughts and questions if you want useful help. In addition, you will need to discuss what you expect to provide the source signal to your multistage amplifier and what kind of power output you also expect (if power is your goal) or what voltage swing you need (if power is not your goal for the output.)

Comment: @jonk Thank you for your reply and apologize for the lateness, I was busy finishing off the assignment. Could you please elaborate on your point about them being too high and how that relates to the bjt beta?

Comment: @CuriosityStrikes The voltage divider that the biasing resistors represent can be replaced by a Thevenin voltage and a Thevenin resistance. The base recombination current is a function of beta, which can vary widely between two BJTs (even from the same package.) This base recombination current creates a voltage drop as it passes through the Thevenin equivalent resistance of the biasing pair. That voltage drop affects the base voltage. And that affects the operating collector current.

Comment: @CuriosityStrikes If you need me to elaborate on this, I'd be fine with that. I will be out for a few hours today, though.

Answer (score 2):

When BJT's are used to linearly amplify signals, the bias point of the collector should be designed in order to:

1. Allow for maximum Vc swing
2. Keep the transistor biased in active region during Vc swing

To answer your question:

if Vc doesn't clip to the power supply value and the BJT remains in the active region, then it doesn't really matter whether or not the bias point is placed at half of the power supply.

Usually, the maximum swing of Vc is not obtained by placing the static bias point of the collector at half of the power supply.